# How to convert a video to images with ffmpeg by choosing the numbering?

Tags: image, ffmpeg, command-line

I use ffmpeg to convert my video demo.mp4 into images in the *./frames* folder with the command:

`ffmpeg -i demo.mp4 -pix_fmt rgba ./frames/%08d.png`

I get:

```
00000001.png    00000035.png    00000069.png    00000103.png    00000137.png
00000002.png    00000036.png    00000070.png    00000104.png    00000138.png
00000003.png    00000037.png    00000071.png    00000105.png    00000139.png
00000004.png    00000038.png    00000072.png    00000106.png    00000140.png
00000005.png    00000039.png    00000073.png    00000107.png    00000141.png
00000006.png    00000040.png    00000074.png    00000108.png    00000142.png
00000007.png    00000041.png    00000075.png    00000109.png    00000143.png
00000008.png    00000042.png    00000076.png    00000110.png    00000144.png
00000009.png    00000043.png    00000077.png    00000111.png    00000145.png
00000010.png    00000044.png    00000078.png    00000112.png    00000146.png
00000011.png    00000045.png    00000079.png    00000113.png    00000147.png
00000012.png    00000046.png    00000080.png    00000114.png    00000148.png
00000013.png    00000047.png    00000081.png    00000115.png    00000149.png
00000014.png    00000048.png    00000082.png    00000116.png    00000150.png
00000015.png    00000049.png    00000083.png    00000117.png    00000151.png
00000016.png    00000050.png    00000084.png    00000118.png    00000152.png
00000017.png    00000051.png    00000085.png    00000119.png    00000153.png
00000018.png    00000052.png    00000086.png    00000120.png    00000154.png
00000019.png    00000053.png    00000087.png    00000121.png    00000155.png
00000020.png    00000054.png    00000088.png    00000122.png    00000156.png
00000021.png    00000055.png    00000089.png    00000123.png    00000157.png
00000022.png    00000056.png    00000090.png    00000124.png    00000158.png
00000023.png    00000057.png    00000091.png    00000125.png    00000159.png
00000024.png    00000058.png    00000092.png    00000126.png    00000160.png
00000025.png    00000059.png    00000093.png    00000127.png    00000161.png
00000026.png    00000060.png    00000094.png    00000128.png    00000162.png
00000027.png    00000061.png    00000095.png    00000129.png    00000163.png
00000028.png    00000062.png    00000096.png    00000130.png    00000164.png
00000029.png    00000063.png    00000097.png    00000131.png    00000165.png
00000030.png    00000064.png    00000098.png    00000132.png    00000166.png
00000031.png    00000065.png    00000099.png    00000133.png    00000167.png
00000032.png    00000066.png    00000100.png    00000134.png    00000168.png
00000033.png    00000067.png    00000101.png    00000135.png    00000169.png
00000034.png    00000068.png    00000102.png    00000136.png
```

I would like to get the same results with a numbering **starting from 0** such as:

```
00000000.png    
00000001.png
..
```

How can I do this with ffmpeg?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can start with `frames/00000000.png` like this:

```
ffmpeg ... -start_number 0 frames/%08d.png
```

---

**How do I know this?**

Unlike many answers on `ffmpeg` which just tell you something with no context or explanation, I want to teach you [how to fish](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/give_a_man_a_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_day;_teach_a_man_to_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_lifetime) - don't worry, it's not entirely altruistic because I will likely refer back to it myself

You are generating a sequence of images, so I need to work out which *"muxer"* you are using, and then work out its configurable parameters. So, first, you can get a list of *"muxers"* like this:

```
ffmpeg -v warning -muxers
```

but that generates too much stuff, so let's just find any lines that contain *"sequence"*:

```
ffmpeg -v warning -muxers | grep -i seq
E image2          image2 sequence
E image2pipe      piped image2 sequence
```

So, I can tell you must be using the `image2` *"muxer"*. Now I want to know what options it supports:

```
ffmpeg -v warning -h muxer=image2       
Muxer image2 [image2 sequence]:
    Common extensions: bmp,dpx,exr,jls,jpeg,jpg,jxl,ljpg,pam,pbm,pcx,pfm,pgm,pgmyuv,phm,png,ppm,sgi,tga,tif,tiff,jp2,j2c,j2k,xwd,sun,ras,rs,im1,im8,im24,sunras,vbn,xbm,xface,pix,y,avif,qoi.
    Default video codec: mjpeg.
image2 muxer AVOptions:
  -update            <boolean>    E.......... continuously overwrite one file (default false)
  -start_number      <int>        E.......... set first number in the sequence (from 0 to INT_MAX) (default 1)
  -strftime          <boolean>    E.......... use strftime for filename (default false)
  -frame_pts         <boolean>    E.......... use current frame pts for filename (default false)
  -atomic_writing    <boolean>    E.......... write files atomically (using temporary files and renames) (default false)
  -protocol_opts     <dictionary> E.......... specify protocol options for the opened files
```

So, now I can see you need `-start_number` - and my older, more forgetful self will also know in future.